# Python How to find duplicate values in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, duplicates

Okay I was wondering how I can find duplicate values for a single key in a dictionary.

so I have

```
import collections
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 1), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'blue': [2, 4], 'yellow': [1, 1], 'red': [1]})
```

As you can see "Yellow" has duplicate values.

I was wondering, what is the best pythonic way of finding out if there are duplicate values within a key in the dictionary. And after finding them, removing them from the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check before you append:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    if v not in d[k]: # if value not in list already
        d[k].append(v)
```

Or use a set to store the values:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].add(v) # sets don't have duplicates so we don't need a check here
```

If you don't want the `defaultdict(<class 'list'>` output just make d a normal dict with `dict(d)` or use `dict.setdefault` using a normal dict,

```
d = {}
for k, v in s:
    d.setdefault(k,set())
    d[k].add(v)
```

Comment: one more question, this may be a bit off topic... but do you know how I can get rid of: defaultdict(<class 'list'>,...) from the output.

Comment: You could turn it into a normal dict `dict(d)` or just use a normal dict to start with using `setdefault`