# How to extract all occurrences of a JSON object that share a duplicate key:value pair?

Tags: python, json

I am writing a python script that reads a large JSON file containing data from an API, and iterates through all the objects. I want to extract all objects that have a specific matching/duplicate "key:value", and save it to a separate JSON file.

Currently, I have it almost doing this, however the one flaw in my code that I cannot fix is that it skips the first occurrence of the duplicate object, and does not add it to my `dupObjects` list. I have an `OrderedDict` keeping track of unique objects, and a regular list for duplicate objects. I know this means that when I add the second occurrence, I must add the first (unique) object, but how would I create a conditional statement that only does this once per unique object?

This is my code at the moment:

```
import collections import OrderedDict
import json

with open('input.json') as data:
    data = json.load(data)

uniqueObjects = OrderedDict()
dupObjects = list()

for d in data:
    value = d["key"]

    if value in uniqueObjects:
        # dupObjects.append(uniqueObjects[hostname])
        dupHostnames.append(d)

    if value not in uniqueObjects:
        uniqueObjects[value] = d

with open('duplicates.json', 'w') as g:
    json.dump(dupObjects, g, indent=4)
```

Where you see that one commented line is where I tried to just add the object from the `OrderedList` to my list, but that causes it to add it as many times as there are duplicates. I only want it to add it one time.

**Edit:**

There are several unique objects that have duplicates. I'm looking for some conditional statement that can add the first occurrence of an object that has duplicates, once per unique object.

Comment: is there any particular reason you are using an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga At the moment no, but in a previous implementation I needed to preserve the order in which the keys were inserted.

Comment: regular `dict` objects maintain insertion order since Python 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python How to find duplicate values in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080158/python-how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-dictionary)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this line you forgot .keys(), so you skip need values

```
if value in uniqueObjects.keys():
```

And this line

```
if value not in uniqueObjects.keys():
```

Edit #1

My mistake :)
You need to add first duplicate object from uniqueObjects in first if

```
if value in uniqueObjects:
    if uniqueObjects[value] != -1:
        dupObjects.append(uniqueObjects[value])
        uniqueObjects[value] = -1
    dupHostnames.append(d)
```

Edit #2
Try this option, it will write only the first occurrence in duplicates

```
if value in uniqueObjects:
    if uniqueObjects[value] != -1:
        dupObjects.append(uniqueObjects[value])
        uniqueObjects[value] = -1
```

Comment: absolutely incorrect. `.keys()` is unecessary

Comment: Oh, yes. You need to add first duplicate object from dictionary  in first If

Comment: Try my first edit, it solves your problem

Comment: @attila, if you need only first occurrence in duplicates list, use the second edit.

Comment: @Lakerr Thank you so much! I used your first edit. Never fails to amuse me how I always overthink problems when there are such simple solutions to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by key.
Using `itertools`:

```
def by_key(element):
    return ["key"]

grouped_by_key = itertools.groupby(data, key_func=by_key)
```

Then is just a matter of finding groups that have more than one element.

For details check: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#grouping-elements